# How to add SSR to Vue-cli webpack?

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to follow that link, and implement it on [VueCli webpack template.](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/ssr.html#Simple-SSR-with-the-Express-Web-Server).

Then i go to dev-server.js and create * route, to return as that link:

```js
renderer.renderToString(require('./src/main'), function (err, html){ 
   //code here
})
```

But that require keeps giving me error, that was not possible to load.
Here it's my main js:

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'

const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  template: '<App/>',
  components: { App }
})
```

If someone can help, i'll appreciate!

Comment: Did you find any solution ?

Comment: Have you placed the `const renderer = require('vue-server-renderer').createRenderer()`  above the `renderer.renderToString` function?